# Removing certain elements from a selector binded to the body

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick

I have a `click` event binded to the body element but I don't want it to fire for when the user clicks on certain elements, that being when the element has an attribute of `data-dropdown-target`, however what I have tried isn't working, it always fires.

**CodePen:** http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ORQkrb

**HTML:**

```
<body>
  <div class="foo">foo</div>
  <div class="bar" data-dropdown-target="something">bar</div>
  <div class="moo">moo</div>
</body>
```

**CSS:**

```
.foo, .bar, .moo {
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 5px;
}

.foo {
  background-color: gray;
}

.bar {
  background-color: teal;
}

.moo {
  background-color: green;
}
```

**JS:**

```
$('body').not('[data-dropdown-target]').on('click', function(e) {

    console.log('Hi!');

});
```

I assume this is because it is *trying* to remove `body` elements that have this attribute, rather than it's children - correct?

How do I go about stopping it from firing on children elements that have this attribute - do I have to loop through everything, as I would like to avoid that because of performance reasons, especially since it's on the body.

Comment: According your example: The line `$('body').not('[data-dropdown-target]').on('click', function(e) {});` seems not work, but when I changed `$("body").not()` to `$("body".find("div:not()")`it seems to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually your code try to bind event click on every `<body>` without `data-dropdown-target` attribute.

This could solve your problem :

```js
$('body').on('click', function(e) {
    if($(e.target).data('dropdown-target') || $(e.target).parents('[data-dropdown-target]').length !== 0) return false;
    console.log('Hi!');

});
```

```css
.foo, .bar, .moo {
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 5px;
}

.foo {
  background-color: gray;
}

.bar {
  background-color: teal;
}

.moo {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
  
  <div class="foo">foo</div>
  <div class="bar" data-dropdown-target="something">bar</div>
  <div data-dropdown-target="something">
    <div class="moo">moo</div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Yeah I thought that was what was happening; your idea worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The `not` selector just remove the body element if it has `[data-dropdown-target]` attribute.

> Remove elements from the set of matched elements.

```
$('body').on('click', function(e) {

    console.log('Hi!');

});

$('[data-dropdown-target]').on('click',function(e){
 return false;
});
```